# How to use ARRAYFORMULA with QUERY in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I have a query that needs to be run for every row in a list. It works nicely when written for a single row:

```
QUERY(MaraRankData,
  "select J,I,H,G,F,E where 
    A='"&E3&"' and 
    B='"&B3&"' and 
    C="&C3&" and 
    D="&D3&"",
  0
)
```

That outputs a row of data, as desired. But when I wrap it in ARRAYFORMULA, it still only outputs one row instead of many:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
  QUERY(MaraRankData,
    "select J,I,H,G,F,E where 
      A='"&E3:E&"' and 
      B='"&B3:B&"' and 
      C="&C3:C&" and 
      D="&D3:D&"",
    0)
)
```

Google Sheets isn't throwing any errors, so I don't know what I'm doing wrong. How can I get ARRAYFORMULA to work with my QUERY so I don't have to repeat the formula on every row?

Comment: To support the comment by red red wine about wrapping a Query() formula with an Arrayformula. It is unnecessary to wrap any formula that already returns/produces an array type result. I.e. don't apply  Arrayformula to "Filter", Unique," "Transpose," etc.

Comment: Also most of the time you can use a Query, the Filter formula will work. I bet you can solve your problem easier that way.

Comment: @Xzila If you have a way of doing this with `filter`, please post an answer: I'd be interested in such a solution.

Comment: `=FILTER({E:E,F:F,G:G,H:H,I:I,J:J},A3:A=E3:E)` The first part is just to re-order the columns in the curly brackets. The second is because A to E seems like the only column that mattered as B looks at itself, C looks at itself, etc. Really though a data set would be nice, and perhaps more explanation on the problem. Maybe I just don't understand.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `arrayformula(query(...))` combination is not supported; there is no concept of a `query` processing an array of arrays or executing an array of query strings.

You have two options: (a) repeat `query` on every row; (b) use [`vlookup`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318?hl=en) to retrieve columns of data, as explained below. For example:

```
=arrayformula(vlookup(E3:E, {A3:A, J3:J}, 2, false))
```

takes one element of E3:E at a time, finds this element in column A, and retrieves the corresponding element of column J. With this approach you would need six separate vlookups to get the columns J,I,H,G,F,E, but you won't need a separate command for each row.

A complication is that `vlookup` accepts only one search key, and you want to search by 4 parameters,

```
A='"&E3&"' and 
B='"&B3&"' and 
C="&C3&" and 
D="&D3&
```

This can be worked around by concatenating these into one search key: you can have a column like Z,

```
=arrayformula(E3:E & "|" & B3:B & "|" & C3:C & "|" & D3:D)
```

which concatenates four search parameters into one pipe-delimited search key. Do the same for the table to be searched, and then compare these keys using `vlookup`.

Comment: Regarding the first statement, Nesting query inside of arrayformula works for the first argument. See http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/97658/88163