# How to use INDIRECT to create a dynamic length range?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

## Part 1

To create a dynamic length range I think I should be using `INDIRECT()` in some way but just can't quite get my head around how.

How can I use the function `counta()` as the end of each column's chosen range?

## Part 2

I'm using Google Sheets but I suspect the answer may be the same for Excel as well.

I have two columns full of string data that are dynamically pulled from a website, therefore I can't know for certain how long the columns will be.  I wish to combine them into a single column, so have been using

```
={ARRAYFORMULA(S2:S100);arrayformula(AI2:AI100)}
```

It works but of course I end up with a whole bunch of blanks between the two merged columns, since I am combining each column up to row 100 when there is only data for maybe 50 or so rows each.

I would like to specify the ending of each range, to be the count of that range.  Something like this (which is of course totally improper syntax):

```
={ARRAYFORMULA(S2:Scounta(S:S));arrayformula(AI2:AIcounta(ai:ai)}
```

That's why I need the solution for Part 1.

Comment: I thought I had found a solution in another question, but it turns out that it doesn't work because while it does merge the columns, it skips blanks which are critical in the result.  Does anyone have any idea how to apply an arrayformula to a dynamic range?

Comment: Related: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/97587/merge-two-columns-by-using-query-in-google-sheets/97658

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Concatenate several columns into one in Google Sheets](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/90629/concatenate-several-columns-into-one-in-google-sheets)

Comment: Not a duplicate because I need to include blanks in the result.  That solution clearly focuses on non-blank cells.

Comment: Thought I had it after modifying the solution in that link, but unfortunately it's still a no-go.  I need to be able to define the length of the arrayformula range dynamically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Part 1

> How can I use the function counta() as the end of each column's chosen range?

Use [CONCATENATE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094123?hl=en), [CONCAT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093592?hl=en) or `&` operator.

As you already figured out, to create a dynamic reference use [INDIRECT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377?hl=en). Example:

```
=INDIRECT("S2:S"&COUNTA(S2:S))
```

## Part 2

The final formula is

```
={INDIRECT("S2:S"&COUNTA(S2:S));INDIRECT("AI2:AI"&COUNTA(AI2:AI))}
```

An alternative to get the same result is to use FILTER. The advantage is that it will work for strings and numbers. Example:

```
={FILTER(S2:S,LEN(S2:S);FILTER(AI2:AI,LEN(AI2:AI)}
```

Another alternative is to use QUERY. The advantage of it is that the import formulas could be combined into an array an use it of the data argument of QUERY:

```
=QUERY({import1;import2},"select Col1 where Col1<>'' and Col1<>'Header'")
```

### References

- [Concatenate several columns into one in Google Sheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/90629/concatenate-several-columns-into-one-in-google-sheets)
- [Merge two columns by using QUERY in Google Sheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/97587/merge-two-columns-by-using-query-in-google-sheets/)

Comment: Ah I was so close with indirect!  This finally got it... thanks!