# Find and place in a column, the first non-blank cell in each row from a range of columns

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula, regex, concatenate

I'm attempting to create an ARRAYFORMULA that can extract the first non-blank cell value on each row in a range of columns.

My latest attempt is this:

`=TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE( A2:D6),"select * where Col1 <>'' limit 1",9^99))`

Placed in `F2`, this generates all the output of the range `F2:F6` in the table below.

However it's quite evident that all it does it to concatenate all the cells in each column using a space as a delimiter, so the output does not resemble my expected outcome, shown in `H2:H6` :-(

I've come up with several other formulas, but the all exhibit the same problem. :-(

```
┌───────┬───────┬───────┬───────┬───────┬───┬────────────────┬───┬──────────┐
│       │   A   │   B   │   C   │   D   │ E │       F        │ G │    H     │
├───────┼───────┼───────┼───────┼───────┼───┼────────────────┼───┼──────────┤
│   1   │ Input │ Input │ Input │ Input │   │ Formula/Output │   │ Expected │
├───────┼───────┼───────┼───────┼───────┼───┼────────────────┼───┼──────────┤
│   2   │ Test0 │       │ Test1 │       │   │Test0 Test1     │   │ Test0    │
├───────┼───────┼───────┼───────┼───────┼───┼────────────────┼───┼──────────┤
│   3   │       │       │       │       │   │                │   │          │
├───────┼───────┼───────┼───────┼───────┼───┼────────────────┼───┼──────────┤
│   4   │       │       │       │ Test3 │   │   Test3        │   │ Test3    │
├───────┼───────┼───────┼───────┼───────┼───┼────────────────┼───┼──────────┤
│   5   │       │   5   │       │       │   │ 5              │   │ 5        │
├───────┼───────┼───────┼───────┼───────┼───┼────────────────┼───┼──────────┤
│   6   │       │       │54:74=2│       │   │  54:74=2       │   │ 54:74=2  │
└───────┴───────┴───────┴───────┴───────┴───┴────────────────┴───┴──────────┘
```

So my question is, how can I make an arrayformula or query that I can place in `F2` that will only select the first non-blank value in each row from `F2:D6`, and output the result to `F2:F6`?

Comment: Your question has been edited according to your provided sample image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula that would give you the desired results would be:

```
=ArrayFormula(REGEXREPLACE(ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(TRIM(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(IF(LEN(B3:H8),B3:H8&"★",)&REPT(" "&"♣︎",COLUMN(B3:H3)=COLUMN(H3))),"♣︎")))),"([^★]+).+","$1"))
```

It is a bit convoluted but works fine.

Comment: This is a great answer! It will take me some time to understand it, though. :-)  I made a slight variation, so that a range is always provided as input: `=ArrayFormula(REGEXREPLACE(ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(TRIM(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(IF(LEN(A2:D6), A2:D6&"★",)&REPT(" "&"♣︎",COLUMN(A2:D6)= CELL("col", A2:D6)+COLUMNS(A2:D6)-1)),"♣︎")))),"([^★]+).+","$1"))`

Comment: I'm really curious. How did you come up with this part of the formula: `CONCATENATE(IF(LEN(B3:H8),B3:H8&"★",)&REPT(" "&"♣︎",COLUMN(B3:H3)=COLUMN(H3))),"♣︎")`  ? Especially the use of `IF` in combination with `CONCATENATE`. I guess it's a known pattern, but where can I read more about it?

Answer (score 0):

Try

`=iferror(QUERY(transpose(A2:D2),"Select Col1 where Col1 is not null limit 1",0),"")`

Comment: Good try, tried it too, Unfortunately it only operates on one column at a time. Even when wrapped in an `ARRAYFORMULA()` and with the range changed to `A2:D6`. I updated the question to clarify.

Comment: This may assist https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/97310/how-to-use-arrayformula-with-query-in-google-sheets